# media queries in Yahoo Pure CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, yui-pure-css

I am working on creating my site using Yahoo's Pure CSS modules(http://purecss.io/).  I really like it so far.  One thing I don't understand is how the media queries fit into it.  Here is what it says on their grids page:

> Default Media Queries
>
> When using Responsive Grids, you can control how the grid behaves at
>   specific breakpoints by adding class names. Pure's default responsive
>   grids comes with the following class names and media query
>   breakpoints.
>   [image]

So I want to add some custom handling at the "xl" breakpoint.  How do I do that?  Also, how do I know which class to put my content into?  I have used media queries before.  I just can't quite wrap my head around how they did it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i my self use pure because bootstrap is boring and bloated why not try something out of the box...the break point is easy on the xl query place your css class be that pures grid even they all can be broken so lets say .sidebar you want it gone on xl place that clas there..you can costumize the breakpoint on their site as well for different screen size if thats what your looking for. I hope this helps...but I am not sure if you are using WordPress but my purecss wp theme will be out shortly for developers and designers!

Comment: You should format you answer. It's a mess reading it like this